# r (ggplot2 line graph): changing linetype for errorbars changes them in legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, linegraph

I have a line graph like this one:
[image: graph]

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2), 
  y = c(1.5,1.9,2.1,1.6,1.4,1.8,2.0,1.7), 
  error = c(0.2), 
  group = c("g1","g2","g1","g2","g3","g4","g3","g4"))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = group, linetype = group)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_line() + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = y - error, ymax = y + error),
                linetype = 1, width = 0.5,                                 
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.2)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("g1"="Black", "g2"="Grey", "g3"="Black", "g4"="Grey")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("g1"=1,"g2"=1,"g3"=2,"g4"=2))
```

I need to make it black and white, so with several groups, I used both `color` and `linetype`. When I change line type, I want to have error bars solid although the lines are dotted, so I overrode the linetype for error bars. For some reason, this also changes the legend, so it is no longer clear which line is which.

I know this somehow depends on the `color = group` in `aes`, because when I just had the linetype, the legend was fine. For some reason I just can't find a way to do linetype, color, and solid errorbars at the same time. Anybody know why this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = group, group = group)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=y,linetype = group)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = y - error, ymax = y + error),
                colour = rep(c("black","grey"),4),
                width = 0.1,                                 
                position = "dodge") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("g1"="Black", "g2"="Grey", "g3"="Black", "g4"="Grey")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("g1"=1,"g2"=1,"g3"=2,"g4"=2))
```

You don't need the linetype = group inside ggplot, as the error bars will never use this info. You just make it more complex. linetype will be used only by the lines and the legend. error bars need to know the color and the grouping variable, that's why you include them inside ggplot.

Setting the colours by creating a column:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2), 
                 y = c(1.5,1.9,2.1,1.6,1.4,1.8,2.0,1.7), 
                 error = c(0.2), 
                 group = c("g1","g2","g1","g2","g3","g4","g3","g4"))


df$group_cols = "black"
df$group_cols[df$group %in% c("g2","g4")] = "grey"


ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = group, group = group)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=y,linetype = group)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = y - error, ymax = y + error),
                colour = df$group_cols,
                width = 0.1,                                 
                position = "dodge") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("g1"="Black", "g2"="Grey", "g3"="Black", "g4"="Grey")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("g1"=1,"g2"=1,"g3"=2,"g4"=2))
```

Comment: Thanks! This works in the example data, but for some reason, adding the `color` to the errorbar removes the dodge in my real data. The real data has 48 points instead of 8 and the names are a bit different, but otherwise I can't find the difference.
`geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-groupCI, ymax=mean+groupCI),
                  colour=c(rep(c("grey","black","black","grey"),12)), 
                  width = .2,
                  position=position_dodge(width=0.2)) +`
(sorry for formatting, how should I show code in a comment?)
I tried your simpler `position="dodge"` but it was not that.

Comment: Also, do you know what is the reason it behaves like that? When the color definition is not present in the `geom_errorbar`, the legend is shown wrong - why does the errorbar definition change the legend?

Comment: colour = c(rep(c("black","grey"),4)) works because in the example data the  df$group is g1 g2 g1 g2 g3 g4 g3 g4. The order matters here as it is a manual setting. Check the order in your big dataset. Does it go along with colour=c(rep(c("grey","black","black","grey"),12)) ? If not try to create a column df$group_cols and put "black" whenever df$group is g1 or g3, and "grey" otherwise.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was unclear. The colors are fine after my change you saw there, I did realize the order matters. But the **dodge** does not work anymore after adding the color setting.

Comment: That shouldn't be possible. Having more groups shouldn't affect the dodge. Any chance you added something more to your code? linetype in another place maybe?

Comment: Just corrected something as c(rep(c("black","grey"),4)) is the same as rep(c("black","grey"),4)

Comment: ...Okay, I don't kwow what happened, but today I tested around, and at some point something happened and the dodge works now. I tested several different things, and at one point `position(width=0.2)` did not work, but when I changed it "dodge" and then back again, suddenly it worked. And what's more, even the older code, which did not work when I used it, run now from history, works also!

Comment: Now that I think of it, I had saved the `ggplot(...)` in a variable and then used the variable instead of the whole definition. I must have had an old definition in that variable, and it probably fixed when I finally ran the new definition following your example. I thought I changed the variable when testing your solution the first time, but I suppose I hadn't, because I can't understand what else it could have been. Thanks, anyway. Marking your solution as accepted.